# LINQ Enumerable in Enumerable - Why?

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

I have a `Ticket` class that contains a List of `User` objects:

```
class Ticket {
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all Users that are related to tickets. I do this:

```
var u = from t in db.Tickets
        where t.Users.Count() > 0
        select t.Users
```

That works but returns a `Enumerable` with 1 element. And that element is an `Enumerable` with the Users.

Why is it nested?

Comment: See my post, but use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is

```
  var u = (from t in db.Tickets from user in t.Users select user).ToList();
```

Then you will have a flattened List of Users.
There's no need to check for `where t.Users.Count() > 0` and if you did need to you should be using where `t.Users.Any()` for efficiency.

Comment: Note that two `from`s translate to `SelectMany()`, so this is equivalent to some of the other solutions.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks.  I should have put both ways for additional brownie points :-)

Comment: based on your rating, I was pretty sure you knew that :) That was just a note to other readers.

Comment: @Phil: please correct your syntax. `u` is declared twice. I used this query: `var u = (from t in db.Tickets from user in t.Users select user).ToList();`

Comment: He doesn't really need the ToList() at the end.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the syntax error.  You don't *need* the .ToList() but if you use it, the query will be evaluated immediately instead of deferred to when you iterate over the results.

Answer (score 4):

Because you select a `IEnumerable<Users>` of `List<User>`...

The second Enumerable is your `List<User>`

You can flatten that with the following query.

```
db.Tickets.Where(t => t.Users.Any()).SelectMany(t => t.Users)
```

`Any()` is much faster than `Count() > 0` because it will stop couting at the first occurence, Count iterate on the full list of users you have

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't merge in one list all t.Users (t0.Users, t1.Users...). You need to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge it to IEnumerable like this:
    db.Tickets.Where(t => t.Users.Count() > 0).SelectMany(t => t.Users)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
var u = (from t in db.Tickets
         from u in t.Users
         select u).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the query i supose you want to have all the user in the tickets.

You can solve this like this:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

foreach(List<user> u in  db.Tickets.where(ticket => ticktet.Users.Count() > 0).select(ticket => ticket.Users)){
users.AddAll(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SelectMany method is what you want. From the MSDN documentation:

"Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable(Of T) and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence."

So you take all the tickets and get all the users for each ticket so the resulting list will be a list of users. You also might want to use the Distinct method as well to remove duplicate users. I'm assuming that a user might be associated with more than one ticket.

Answer (score -1):

First: A LINQ-Query will always return an enumerable.

Second: Your t.Users is a List, which implements IEnumerable aswell.

So the outer enumerable is the linq resultset and the inner one the actual first result that can be cast back to a list of users like

```
var u = from t in db.Tickets
       where t.Users.Count() > 0
       select (t.Users as List<User)
```

Comment: what about FirstOrDefault() that does not return an Enumerable?

Comment: It returns the first Object in the resultset(Enumerable) or - if the resultset is empty - a default object of the correct type.

Comment: it returns the First TSource, from an IEnumerable<TSource> not specifically an Enumerable object. MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Comment: Then correct you answer as it incorrect that's all I pointed out, not all Linq queries return an Enumerable!

Comment: I still consider my answer correct as FirstOrDefault operates on a finished linq query and not inside the query

Comment: A query *typically* always returns an enumerable, but that is a *convention*, not a *guarantee*. A query expression can be of any type whatsoever, including void! It is *extraordinarily* bad practice to implement the query pattern in such a way that a query has a type that is not a sequence of some sort, but it is certainly possible.